# A sequence of equicontinuous functions, are their inverse functions also equicontinuous under some assumptions

Tags: real-analysis

If this sequence of functions satisfy the following assumptions:

1. increasing and 1-to-1 function on an interval.
2. convergent to a known function (all uniformly convergent if necessary)

Is it true that the set of inverse of functions from this sequence is also equicontinuous? If that is true, how to prove it?

Comment: what does it mean for a function to be convergent?

Comment: Sorry. I mean this family of functions are convergent.

Comment: how does a family of functions converge?

Comment: wait do you know the functions from the family are equicontinuous?

Comment: also are the functions increasing or is the sequence increasing?

Comment: @Pelto the functions are increasing. Sorry for misunderstanding. I rephrase the question.

Comment: @zhw. I rephrase the question, I mean a sequence of functions.

Comment: Do you know anything about the convergence of the sequence of inverse functions?

Did you see this problem in a book?

Comment: @Pelto, No, it's for one lemma I need to show. And no, I don't know the convergence of inverse functions, actually if inverse functions converge uniformly, then they are equicontinuous. I already figured it out myself, need a few more assumptions: #2 assumption has to be uniform convergent, all the functions need to be positive.